# How do Physicists View Position?

Tags: spacetime, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

I started thinking about what it means to know the position of something. That thought lead me down this weird path that now makes me wonder if something can actually ever have a position at all. 
For example, I have never stayed in a position. I have never stayed in the same place. My feet, the earth, the sun and galaxy have always been moving me. This is true for not just me, but everything, electrons, photons, etc. Then I though, to myself, "Well, you actually were in positions, but you were just always moving through them." Okay, so position is just a snapshot of where something is in time and space. 
But when I did research on position on this site and a few videos as well, like this one, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uwEgbSU6omI. I never found info that suggested that a position was always fleeting. The definitions seemed to say that positions could be static. 
Because position is connected to space and time I suspect that relativity comes into to play. 
So my question is this: Can something have a position or is position always changing?

Note: There were no tags that matched the question.

Comment: Why the down vote, David?

Comment: I didn't downvote. I just removed the superposition tag, which has nothing to do with "position".

Comment: Too short to be an answer: At least in classical mechanics (where time is **the** independent variable of motion), physicists view position as a function of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All position is relative, and it's really just a label. You arbitrarily choose an origin and coordinate system (called an atlas) and a way to measure distances (called a metric), and then you use that to define your position relative to the origin. One of the fundamental rules when constructing theories in physics is that they shouldn't depend on how you define position, because it's entirely arbitrary.

Comment: IMO, this answer misses the point, which is that an object's "position", however defined, is a function of time, just as its velocity.

Comment: @DavidHammen I disagree. You can define a curve that tells you how an object's position changes with some parameter, but that curve is not the position. The output of the curve is a position.

Comment: I think this misses the point.  The issue of the OP is whether you can have a static position or if position is "fleeting": your answer doesn't address this.